# Minecraft 1.8.9 Freezing my computer

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, freeze, crash, minecraft

At first when I join it seems fine, but when I try to join a server it freezes and my mouse can't click anything. If I tab to a different window I can't click on anything. The only way to fix it is by hard restarting my computer.

Comment: Do you have swap space? Read `man free mkswap swapon fallocate fstab`. Knowing nothing about your hardware,  I'll recommend 1.0 to 1.5 times the RAM you have. Without swap, when programs run out of memory, the kernel runs the "OOM-Killer", which picks a task to kill to free memory. With swap, the system slows down a little, until programs exceed RAM+Swap, then the OOM-Killer. Also with swap >= RAM size, you can hibernate. Swap space must be contiguous (all in one disk block). `dd` is NOT capable of creating contiguous files.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Don't use Add Comment, or you'll classify yourself as "Does Not Follow Instructions (DNFI)", and I'll ignore you. I view DNFIs as unhelpable.